# JQuery Element not dropping 

Tags: jquery

I have this page am working on https://schedule.nookal.com/ and as you can see, the "events" are draggable and droppable on each other. I want to make something like "overlapping events" (2 events at a time). And as you can notice too, the events are resizable (you can add duration by resizing the bottom), the problem is that jQuery isn't detecting the new resized portion of the div (it's only detecting its middle) I want the elements to overlap whenever there is a collision between the two durations, not only the middle... Also, tolerance:"touch" doesn't seem to work... I'm thinking of a problem in CSS.. Please help

```
$(".DivBG[data-occupied=1]").droppable({
accept: $(".DivBG[data-occupied=1]"),
hoverClass: "touch",
greedy: true,
over: function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.draggable).css("width", "125px");
    $(ui.draggable).css("margin-left", "125px");
    $(this).css("width", "125px");
},
out: function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.draggable).css("width", "250px");
    $(ui.draggable).css("margin-left", "0px");
    $(this).css("width", "250px");
    $(ui.draggable).removeClass("overlapdraggable");
} 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are calculating Widths and Heights with Jquery

```
var width = $(element).css('width');
```

Will always take the CSS width that does not include margin, padding or borders. In essence it does not take the box model into account.

Instead you can guarantee to always get the [innerWidth](http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/) with:

```
var width = $(element).innerWidth();
```

Or the [.outerWidth](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) with

```
var width = $(element).outerWidth();
```

If you pass `true` to outerWidth() it includes the margin also (ie the entire box model)

```
var width = $(element).outerWidth(true);
```

When you are setting widths and heights with Jquery. Width, margin, padding and border must be explicitly stated.

In your code above, you set the necessary dimensions in Jquery but you lack any width / height checks to constrain your div's to fit inside the `outerWidth` that you want for each element.